# Issue with the last part of my result page

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I need help on the last part of my coding.  I have it where when you look up a name in the search box it pulls up that persons info.  I need help on the part where when I type a persons name I can look it up by weeks. So type name in box click on a week and click on the submit button and it will show me all results from that person in that week. The week part is not working right.

```
  Step 1: Type a first and last name  
  Step 2: Pick a week  
  Step 3: click on the submit button  
  Results: Shows the results of patient_name and all the care_providers in that week. 
  IN order care_provider, patient_name, date_of_service, time_in, time_out, and remarks. 

  I have the search box working to search for patient_name but not the week part.
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `info` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `care_provider` varchar(255),
  `patient_name` varchar(255),
  `date_of_service` date(10), //for the week part 
  `time_in` time(10),
  `time_out` time(10),
  `remarks` varchar(255),
```

The code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("prive_ts", $con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM info";


if (isset($_POST['search_box']) && $_POST['search_box']) {
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
    $sql .= " WHERE patient_name = '{$search_term}' ";
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="results38.php">

Search: <input type="text" name="search_box" value="" />
<input type="week" name="week" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Look up Patient ...">

</form>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">

<tr>

    <td><strong>Care Provider</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Patient Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Date of Time</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Time In</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Time Out</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Remarks</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['care_provider']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['patient_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['date_of_service']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['time_in']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['time_out']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: You are not passing the week to the mysql query.also you might wanna mention the format of the value which you are going to enter in the `week` field.is it a date time value, numeric value etc.

Comment: @Himal The `date_of_service` is going to be for the week part to get the week info from the database. date_of_service(date).

Comment: yes, i understand.are you going to enter a date in the week field? can you give me a sample input ?

Comment: @Himal Here is a link for the sample [Login Page](http://priveinfo.dx.am/index.php) user test pass test. Also a link for the [Results Page](http://priveinfo.dx.am/results38.php). Don't worry about the error on the page free webhosting site dont like the session_start().

Comment: i'm asking about the value you are going to enter into week field.is it a date time, just a week number.you have to figure out the correct week from that week input field and compare it against the DB.

Comment: @Himal I have it set up as DATE in the database. On the result page its set up as week numbers.

Comment: @Himal I did as you said and I get this error `Unknown column 'W37' in 'where clause'` On the form I have `<input type="date" name="date_of_service"/>` and on the admin result page form I have it `<input type="week" name="week" value="" />`. The week is looking for all the dates in that week from the `DATE` part from the form side.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the 'week' to your SQL query.

According to the additional info on comments, you might wanna try something like this

```
if (isset($_POST['search_box']) && $_POST['search_box']) {

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
    $week = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['week']);

    $sql .= " WHERE patient_name = '{$search_term}' AND WEEK(date_of_service) = {$week}";
}
```

Comment: Would it be easy if it was a drop down menu with the first and last date of the weeks. sample Sept. 7, 2014 - Sept. 13, 2014 and so on.